# node 19 hangs when installing Realm

Tags: node.js, react-native, realm

I am trying to install realm in a fresh react-native project. but when I run this command yarn add realm or npm I realm it always stop on this step.

[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⠄ realm
and nothing is happening. I have tried many version to install but same issue,

Comment: It sounds like the standard installation process is not being followed. Please review [Install Realm: React Native](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/) as that process works and is verified.

Comment: realm working on lower version and is working fine. but on node 19 its hangs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @engr-aftab-ufaq said, installing `nvm` and then using the latest LTS version (v18.14.0 as I'm writing), then re-running `npm install realm`, fixed the problem for me

Comment: we need a solution on node 19 not on lower versions

Answer (score 1):

For node 19, you can try this

npm install --save realm@11.4.0

Please check for compatibility with you node and react native version:  https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md

Comment: its still not working. not an issue with node but this is is the problem with realm.